# Is it possible to create sdf file and copy it to isolated storage

Tags: c#, sql, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, isolatedstorage

I want to create one sdf file using SDFViewer and then copy it to isolated storage because I don't want add data manually in the code. Is that possible? If yes how I can do that? Do I need to add as item in project?

How then I should modify this?

`const string ConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/Questions.sdf";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [How to deploy a Reference Database with a Windows Phone Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286411%28v=vs.92%29)

Hope that helps